# Reading data from an external source (CSV)

Tags: javascript, csv, dom

I'm trying to read a CSV file from dropbox and display some of its contents in a web site.
What I have done so far is, I read the data and logged it to console.

But I couldn't display it on website because I'm getting "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" error.

Here is my code: http://jsbin.com/weqiviguci/1/edit?html,js,console,output

What I am doing wrong? Can you please show me the correct way to do it in a JSBin or JFFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Papa.parse("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/wsnizh4lyugxd60/data.csv", {
  download: true,
  header: true,
  complete: function(results) {
    var items = [];
    results.data.forEach(function(item, index) {
      items.push('<div id="csvdata' + index + '">' + item.batteryLevel + '</div>');
    });

    if (items.length > 0) {
      var el = document.getElementById('csvdata');
      el.innerHTML = items.join('');
    }
  }      
});
```

Comment: el.innerHTML = items.join(''); line gives "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" error.

Comment: It means there are no element with id="csvdata". It was in your code on jsbin, so I decide to use it.